# Sort Opportunity List View by Stage inside Account

Tags: sales

I have a requirement in which I need to sort the Opportunity List View inside Account by Stage rather then Closed Date, but am not being able to.
*Each of these Opportunities below have two different Sales Processes.

I have done a search online, but all I found was results from Salesforce Ideas.

Is there any way I can accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: Is this somehow complicated by the fact you are on a Service Cloud Console? In that case you should have explained this a little bit more.

Comment: You are right, I really apologize for the confusion and tried to make my comment a bit more clear. I also moved to the Sales app now. I'm still a fairly new Admin and since the beginning at still my first job I've only been working with Service Cloud.

Comment: Doesn't it sort when you click on "Stage"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your list view, you can just click on the Header (view image below) and it will sort it for you.
[image]

However, if you want a seperate list view, for example, I want a list view to only see all the Opportunities that are in "Closed Won" stage. Then if you have access, to the **List View Controls** (image below)

[image]

Click on it and select **New**, then enter your preferred list view name and choose who can view the list you are creating. Then for your filters, you can add Stage = (Your preferred opportunity StageName). Then now, if you want to view only closed Won opportunity then you can select this list view that you have just created.